# How can I "double overload" an operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

If I have a database-like class, and I want to do something like this:

object[1] == otherObject;

How do I "double overload" operator[] and operator==?

Comment: Just overload them separately and the compiler will take care of it. What's the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`object[1]` returns an object of `someType`. You need to overload `operator==` on that `someType`.

Comment: OK but I'm getting this error: "..\Database.cpp:36: error: no match for 'operator==' in 'Database::operator[](unsigned int) const(x) == inRecord'"

Comment: Might be easier to figure out if you post a new question with some of the relevant code :)

Comment: What are the types of `inRecord` and return value of `operator[] const`? Have you overloaded `operator==` for the return value of `operator[]` as a non-const method?

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is simply two separate operator overloads. Just make sure that the parameter to `operator ==` matches the return type of `operator []`.

Answer (score 2):

I was really confused at first by the wording of the question, but now I think I understand. You can't do this directly; but you can achieve the same effect. The idea is to make `operator[]` return a *proxy object*. For the proxy object, you can provide `operator==` with custom behavior for comparison. I've seen std::map's operator[] implemented this way on some older, more obscure standard library implementations.

Example (let's say object[1] normally returns Foo&):

```
class SomeProxy
{
private:
    Foo* f;
public:
    explicit SomeProxy(Foo& i_f): f(&i_f) {}
    operator Foo&() const {return *f;}
};

SomeProxy Database::operator[](unsigned int n)
{
     return SomeProxy(some_array + n);
}

bool operator==(const SomeProxy& lhs, const Foo& rhs)
{
    // provide custom behavior
}


// also provide custom behavior for these:
bool operator==(const SomeProxy& lhs, const SomeProxy& rhs);
bool operator==(const Foo& lhs, const SomeProxy& rhs);
```

Note: it seems kind of odd that you want to overload the meaning of a comparison operator in such a case (proxy objects are often used for custom assignment behavior with associative structures or for fancy metatemplate programming) but for comparison they should typically provide the same meaning as working with `Foo` directly, e.g. Nevertheless, here's the way to do it: a way to get custom behavior through `operator==` that is only applicable when using an overloaded `operator[]` in the same expression.

If you want to make this thorough, then make the constructors of SomeProxy private and make Database a friend. This way, only the Database: can create those objects (through operator[] in this case) and the client won't be able to copy it (which he shouldn't), only get a Foo object/reference out of it or use the proxy returned in an expression.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think of operator overloading as anything special, they are just like normal function overloading. Two functions having the same name can be overloaded given that they have different signatures.   (You can't overload 2 functions only by the return type by the way.  That is not just for operator overloading, it is for all overloading of functions in general.)

So simply like this:

```
class B {};
class C {};
class A
{
  bool operator==(const B& b)
  {
      //Put logic here
      return true;
  }

  bool operator==(const C& c)
  {
      //Put logic here
      return true;
  }

};
```

The above code will allow you to compare an object of type `A` with an object of type `B`.  It will also allow you to compare an object of type `A` with an object of type `C`.